# Is file versioning is supporting in Azure Datalake?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-files

I need to know file versioning is supporting in azure data lake or not?. if i upload two files with same name, second file will be stored with some file version like 1.1. is it possible or not?. if its possible how we can achieve this?

Comment: No, [Not possible yet](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/17109583-versioning-store-multiple-versions-of-a-file-in-a). See also [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4eea5ca5-10fc-403a-93e0-49f86db8cc65/file-versioning?forum=AzureDataLake)

Answer (score 1):

Based on these links I would say it is not possible yet
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/17109583-versioning-store-multiple-versions-of-a-file-in-a

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4eea5ca5-10fc-403a-93e0-49f86db8cc65/file-versioning?forum=AzureDataLake

Comment: Then How can i achieve file versioning? i have to implement custom logic for that. means if the file with name is exists in directory  means i have to create version for that file or any other way is there?

Comment: Right now it means you need to do a custom solution.  My suggestion would be move the  existing file to a cold storage location and append the date/time to the filename and then upload the new one.